# PartialView is opening in another page

Tags: .net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a searchfield which triggers a request function returning partial view and according to result I want to show the response in partial view under the searchfield in the same page. User writes something to textfield and clicks the search button then under them result shows. I get the result but my partialview is opening in another page instead of under the searchfield in the same page. Also looks like my onClick function does not trigger.

My main View:

```
 <div class="container">

        <!-- Outer Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6 p-3">
                <form class="form-group" method="post" action="/Books/BookDetail">
                   
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="barcodes" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small bg-gray-200" placeholder="Kitap Barkodunu giriniz..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="myBtn" name="myBtn" onclick="showBook">
                            <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
            </div>    
            <br />
            <div id="partialContent">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function showBook() {
            $('#partialContent').load("/Controllers/BooksController/BookDetail");
        }
    </script>
```

Book Detail Controller:

```
public IActionResult BookDetail(string barcodes)
         {
            var request = $"?barcodes={barcodes}";
            var products = _httpTool.HttpGetAsync<List<Products>>($"{AppSettings.ApiUrl}/GetProducts{request}");       
            if(products.Result.Count != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.result = "Success";
                var product = products.Result[0]; 
                return PartialView("_BookDetailPartial", product);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.result = "Failed";
                return View("AddBook");
            }
           
        }
```

_BookDetailPartial:

```
<div>
    <h4>PartialCame</h4>
    <br />
    <h5>@Model.Author</h5>
</div>
```

What is the problem here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="showBook"
```

should be

```
onclick="showBook()"
```

And this path appears to be wrong: "/Controllers/BooksController/BookDetail" it should most likely be "/Books/BookDetail?barcodes=barcode"

I'm not sure what you mean about the partial view loading in another page. Could you give some more detail please?

Comment: Yes, onClick() is now triggering I forgot that... And what I meant was, partialview is not showing in the same page with my main view. It just redirects to another page like it is completely an another view and showing in that page. It does not render under <div id="partialContent"> but renders in another webpage. Hope It's clear now.

Comment: Take the type="submit" off your button to prevent a postback

Comment: I completely got rid of form. Instead took the parameter in script like function showBook() {
            var barcodes = $("#barcodes").val();
            $('#partialContent').load('/books/bookdetail?barcodes=' + barcodes);
        } now it's working. Thanks for your help!